# I am trying to close modelpopupextender using a button click, this button belongs to another form so modelpopupextender is not able to access it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to close modelpopupextender using a button click, this button belongs to another form so modelpopupextender is not able to accessable.

I have tried to remove the updatepanel as suggested, but it's not working.

This is my form1.aspx (which includes a button, onclick which will display a ModalPopupExtender in which includes grid view)

```
<asp:Button id="btnclick" text="Show Modal Popup" runat="server" >
</asp:Button>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModelPopupExtender1" runat="server"
PopupControlID="pc" TargetControlID="btnclick" OkControlID ="Button2"
CancelControlID="Button1" BackgroundCssClass="bcc" BehaviorID="MPE1">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pc" runat="server" CssClass="pop" Style="display:none;">
<iframe style="width:1003px;height:550px;" id="if"src="EstPopUp.aspx" runat="server"></iframe>
</asp:Panel>
```

This is my EstPopUp.aspx ( Where gridview is dislpayed with save and cancel buttons)

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvContacts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="5"  DataKeyNames="EstimateBreakUpTypeId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvContacts_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="gvContacts_RowDataBound" >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DispOrder">
<ItemTemplate>
<center>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" width="20px" runat="server" Text='<%#
Bind("DispOrder") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</center>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EstBreakUpName">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  ></asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Percentage(%)">
<ItemTemplate>
<center>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" Width="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</center>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3"  runat="server" CssClass="sum"  ></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fte" runat="server" Enabled="true"
TargetControlID="TextBox3" FilterType="Numbers,Custom" ValidChars=".">
</cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>       
<asp:Button class="abc" ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass=".cancel" OnClick="Button2_Click1"></asp:Button >
<br />

</asp:GridView>
```

My expected result is, when cancel button is clicked the modelpopup should disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it works fine.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string url = " form1.aspx";
            Response.Write("<script>top.location='" + url + "';parent.location='" + url + "';</script>");   
    }
```